# Rails: change location of app directory on local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my local machine I have all rails apps in one folder and it became messy.
I want to reorganize them: put clients apps, engines etc. in separate sub-folders.
Should I change something inside apps or I can just move apps folders to another locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can move them without any impact!